# Can someone help me figure out how to create this button with html and css only?

Tags: html, css, button

Can someone help me figure out how to create this button with html and css only? Did try something with afters and `border-radious`, but with no succes. Thanks in advance!

[image]

```css
.button {
    border-top-left-radius: 30px 74px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px 11rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 75px 23px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px 215px;
    background-color: rgb(28, 24, 59);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
  line-height:2;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family:'Helvetica Neue'
}
.button:after{
  background: #1c183b;
    content: "";
    height: 48px;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    right: -1.3em;
    top: 50%;
    width: 48px;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-radius: .4em;
    -webkit-transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s all ease-in-out;

}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Shitty button</a>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Provide code samples.

Comment: https://codepen.io/mikavs/pen/OmzEjW Something like this..

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
.mybtn{
 background:#25214C;
 color:#FFF;
 border-radius:5px 25px 25px 5px;
 padding:15px;
  border-top:none;
  border-left:none;
  border-right:none;
 border-bottom:5px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="mybtn">More Information</button>
```